# Linking file (stylesheets, script files, images and etc..)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem on linking files such as stylesheets, images, database connection file(db.php), script files and etc.. because they are located outside the file where they are included/linked.

For example assuming this is the location of the  main file where everything will be called:

```
my website directory/admin/thefilewhereeverythingwillbecalled.php
```

in `thefilewhereeverythingwillbecalled.php`, I must call the db.php which is located outside the folder that contains `thefilewhereeverythingwillbecalled.php`

e.g. `my website directory/-this is the directory where the db.php is located-/thefilewhereeverythingwillbecalled.php` - ditto the style sheets and script.

However the stylesheets and script are in the folder cssandjs (contains all stylesheets and script files) which this folder are located before the location of the `thefilewhereeverythingwillbecalled.php`

e.g. `my website directory/-here is where the cssandjs folder is located-/thefilewhereeverythingwillbecalled.php`

Generally I'm just having a problem on linking files which is outside from the file where it called those files. Can someone give me an idea how to link it please?

I tried this:

`../cssandjs/style.css`and `./cssandjs/jquery.js` but none of them work

Comment: You can post example of your tries

Comment: Where is the jack hammer, I need to tear down this wall of text.

Comment: @Petah -> lol. I tried my best to edit it. Couldnt understand beyond a point.

Comment: Please add some brea(k|th)space and spend some time on code highlighting

Comment: Edited as best i could and still can't make sense of this "question"...

Comment: You can try using relative paths.  ie if the images directory is at the same level as the current directory do ../images

Comment: Advice: **Use:** white space, correct grammar, short example filenames, a list/tree/diagram to display your directory structure. **Don't:** confuse php include/require with html embedding/linking. **Do:** show your attempts that are causing the problem. If it is private work, show an example that is safe to share that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @Duane After editing it looks like this? I wonder how it looked before!!!!

Comment: why I can't see the `edit` option? I could have give it a shot.

Comment: hahah :D, WHAT A.. ok heres my point, in my admin.php which is located  inside the folder(admin) and that folder which contain the (admin.php) is inside my website directory however, those files that are needed to be called such as stylesheets and javascripts are inside the folder named cssandjs and that folder is located also inside my website directory now the problem is, how do i link them? i tried this one ../cssandjs/style.css and ./cssandjs/jquery.js but none of them work

Comment: hahah :D, WHAT A.. ok heres my point, in my admin.php which is located  inside the folder(admin) and that folder which contain the (admin.php) is inside my website directory however, those files that are needed to be called such as stylesheets and javascripts are inside the folder named cssandjs and that folder is located also inside my website directory now the problem is, how do i link them? i tried this one ../cssandjs/style.css and ./cssandjs/jquery.js but none of them work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct, it's 2 directories up. Try this :

```
../../cssandjs/style.css
```

This will work if /cssandjs/ is in your website directory. 
You should be a bit more specific with your directory names instead of -here is where this is located-

Can't seem to figure out which are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

try to include full path to the files.

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the files like including the directories and files with 
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/dirName/file.ext";

or use relative paths "../dirnName/file.ext";

first method is preferred